# Mongoose aggregate: Cant show the parameter on witch I group as I use replaceRoot

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, grouping, aggregate

I have a Dataset with the followin Schema:

```
Schema({
    'ID': {type:Number},
    'Date': {type:Date},
    'DrivingHours':{type:Number}
})
```

and I like to aggreate by grouping up to the following result:

```
[
    {
        "DrivingHours": [
            {
                "9": 2.6061111111111113,
                "36": 0,
                "54": 0.016944444444444446,
                "Date": "2019-9-1"
            },
            {
                "9": 0.5738888888888889,
                "36": 0,
                "54": 0,
                "Date": "2019-9-2"
            },
           ...
```

as the keys are the IDs of my vehicles. With the following pipline, I came close to my goal, but could not integrate the "Date". Is there a trick how to add this parameter after using '$replaceRoot'?

```
{$facet: {
            DrivingHours: [
                {$group: {_id: {Date: '$Date', ID: '$ID'},
                    ID: {$first: '$ID'},
                    DrivingHours: {$first: '$DrivingHours'}
                }},                    
                {$group: {_id: '$_id.Date',
                    arrDrivingHours: {
                        $push: {'k': { $toString: '$ID' }, 'v':{ $ifNull: [ '$DrivingHours', 0 ] }}
                    }}},
                {'$replaceRoot':{
                    newRoot: {$arrayToObject:'$arrDrivingHours'} 
                    } 
                }
            ]
            }}
```

I am using facet, as I like to add other aspects of the Dataset later on, but that works greate.

Comment: can you also attach on2 demo in here https://mongoplayground.net/ what you have done so far, it will be easy to answer this type of question for others.

Comment: Thanks @SaikatChakrabortty for that nice hint on the playgrond.net. I juste buld up an example with some fake data and in there you can see what I have already realised so far:
https://mongoplayground.net/p/ik4pdq9JF0P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just have to add the Date Object within a "$mergeObjects". So, solution is:

```
{$facet: {
            DrivingHours: [
                {$group: {_id: {Date: '$Date', ID: '$ID'},
                    ID: {$first: '$ID'},
                    DrivingHours: {$first: '$DrivingHours'}
                }},                    
                {$group: {_id: '$_id.Date',
                    arrDrivingHours: {
                        $push: {'k': { $toString: '$ID' }, 'v':{ $ifNull: [ '$DrivingHours', 0 ] }}
                    }}},
                {'$replaceRoot':{
                    newRoot: {"$mergeObjects": [
                        {"Date": "$_id.Date"},
                        {$arrayToObject: "$ObjDrivingHours"}
                        ]
                    } 
                } 
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: And a new playgrund on that including the solution: https://mongoplayground.net/p/1BvoxsxO7ME